# Debug symbols for release build MSVC

Tags: visual-c++

I need to create debug symbols file for my release build in msvc2013 compiler to be able to analyze crash dumps created by breakpad. I add these flags:

```
/MAP /Zi /debug /opt:ref
```

Is it safe to release executable compiled with these flags?

Comment: What does "safe" mean?

Comment: Anything. Is that good idea to use these flags for release build which will be downloaded and installed by some user of my software?